# Get properties of each object in tree of modelview objects

Tags: autodesk-forge

I used this endpoint (GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties) of Model Derivative API for getting properties of each object in modelview tree of RVT file. Now I want to get only the properties of an object in the tree. Metadata endpoint returns GUID of entire tree and not for each family. Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jericko,

This is a requirement that has not been exposed, but the related ticket of wish has been logged with our engineer team:

*DERI-4610: provide parameter for 'request properties' endpoint to filter out limited properties*

I have not a time table when it would be available. Thank you for your understanding and patience!

At this moment, the workaround would be taking advantage of Forge Viewer API, i.e. load the model to browser, then call viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['externalId', 'Category'], function) where you can limit the results to just the two properties 'externalId' and 'Category'. This blog tells more:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method

Sorry for the inconvenience.